# Pandas read_csv wont parse line correctly

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Im having issues trying to read a csv file and parse it correctly with python 2.7 using pandas.

Some lines that fail:

> Europa,2018-04-20,26948,15,Destino,-,CRU-159617-JUN-2018,Origen,Productos incluidos,https://s3.amazonaws.com/cruceros-host/home/host-Cruceros.jpg,Crucero,06,https://www.host.com/cruceros/listado?regionId=7&startDate=2018-06-01&endDate=2018-07-01&adults=2&children=0&childrenAges=,23433,"Espana, Francia, Italia, Malta"
>
> Australasia,2018-05-01,39155,15,Destino,-,CRU-180907-JAN-2019,Origen,Productos incluidos,https://s3.amazonaws.com/cruceros-host/home/host-Cruceros.jpg,Crucero,01,"https://www.host.com/cruceros/listado?regionId=14&startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-02-01&adults=2&children=0&childrenAges=&startPort=Sydney, Australia",34048,"Nueva Zelanda   "

The code:

```
frame = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=raw_file)
```

--
Edit:

The problem im getting is that i ll return a single column with the hole row.

--
Edit2:

The problem was that excel edited some lines acidentally and added " at the and and end of some lines. Now its working properly.

Comment: what do you mean by fail? what error do you get?

Comment: @AsavPatel i wont parse it. it ll return a single column with the hole row.

Comment: did u se the argument sep=','?

Answer (score 0):

### **pandas.Series.str and apply function**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[r'Europa,2018-04-20,26948,15,Destino,-,CRU-159617-JUN-2018,Origen,Productos incluidos,https://s3.amazonaws.com/cruceros-host/home/host-Cruceros.jpg,Crucero,06,https://www.host.com/cruceros/listado?regionId=7&startDate=2018-06-01&endDate=2018-07-01&adults=2&children=0&childrenAges=,23433,"Espana, Francia, Italia, Malta"',
                        r'Australasia,2018-05-01,39155,15,Destino,-,CRU-180907-JAN-2019,Origen,Productos incluidos,https://s3.amazonaws.com/cruceros-host/home/host-Cruceros.jpg,Crucero,01,"https://www.host.com/cruceros/listado?regionId=14&startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-02-01&adults=2&children=0&childrenAges=&startPort=Sydney, Australia",34048,"Nueva Zelanda "']})

df.a = df.a.str.split(',')
for i in range(9):
    df['Col {0}'.format(i)]=df.a.apply(lambda x: x[i])

df['Col 10'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[9:]))
```

---

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using the separator.
Try with this:

```
pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=raw_file, sep=r',')
```

Comment: @Marco It seems that one rows has more column than the other(check the last element). Even if it is between quotes can give problems: "Espana, Francia, Italia, Malta" and "Nueva Zelanda"

Comment: im aware of this but i ll like to tell pandas to ignore everything in between "